# Should I have a Parser for each Type in C++?

Tags: c++, json, parsing

I am currently building a Simple "Level" system for my game, where game objects are composed of Components and the Data in that Components are Stored in JSON. Let's say I have Following Structs:

```
struct SpriteComponent
{
    int textureID;
    std::string resource;
};

struct TransformComponent
{
    Vector3 position;
    Vector3 rotation;
    Vector3 scale;
};
```

where Vector3 is,

```
struct Vector3
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;    
};
```

I need to define my Gameobjects using JSON, so I can load them in my game at runtime. My question is should I have to write a Parsing Code for each different User-defined Type in C++?

I have experience with Unity3D and it came with a Nifty [JSONUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html) which automagically maps to correct Fields(using Reflection if I am not wrong). Are there any libraries that do that in C++? I came across [this Parser](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) which pretty much is limited to accessing each element one-by-one using their respective keys if I am not wrong.

Comment: https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/mapper.html

Comment: Hey @πάνταῥεῖ ! Something like [this](https://github.com/BrainlessLabs/bun) maybe?

Comment: Looks promising at a glance.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Oh Oh! I found a [similar one to Unity's JSONUtility](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer). I am still learning C++. I'll mark this as the right Answer. Thanks for telling me about the Mapper! you were really helpful!

Comment: At my work, doing this I'll use a JSON class in the form of `JSON["x"]= x` when serializing and `x= JSON["x"]` when deserializing. We would be spared to write such a code when C++ gets reflection support (I think it's scheduled for C++23). There are clever people who do things like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abdeAew3gmQ and maybe this https://preshing.com/20180116/a-primitive-reflection-system-in-cpp-part-1/

Comment: @Mirko What about this [library](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer)?

Comment: @VigneshGunasekaran It seems to do the trick (anyway, at my work for space requirements I would not use a json object but a json array to store x, y and z; and that clearly is lying to json, but much shorter).

Comment: @VigneshGunasekaran _"**Yet another** JSON/YAML/Binary serialization library for C++."_ (emphasis mine) tells us all about it. There are tons of json parsing utilities out in the world.  The key point for selection is how good these are fitting with your custom types mapping.

Comment: I'll give it a try and get back in a few days if it did the job for me! Again thanks for the help!

Comment: The [jsoncons](https://github.com/danielaparker/jsoncons) C++ library supports conversion between JSON and C++ data structures. Refer to the [examples](https://github.com/danielaparker/jsoncons/blob/master/doc/Examples.md).

Comment: In https://github.com/nlohmann/json#arbitrary-types-conversions the conversion from/to arbitrary types to/from JSON is described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is usually someone who has already done something you need doing :-)

For C++ I like [nlohmann's JSON header library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) which has proven invaluable so far.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Unity does it through Reflection which is not currently a part of C++. I found this [Library](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer), thanks to guidance from [toπάντα ῥεῖ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/%CF%80%CE%AC%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1-%E1%BF%A5%CE%B5%E1%BF%96)!